# I have a grocery list program that starts with an empty list and the user enters input into the list

Tags: python, list, loops

The user can not only add items to the list but also pop items from the list. I seem to be stuck where the user pops items from the list but the output needs to only show the first and last letter of that item that has been popped. for example

```
["Oranges" , "Apples" , "Mangoes"]
["O-----s" , "Apples" , "Mangoes"]
```

The code below is what I have so far:

```
add_item = []
choice = 0
while(True):
    choice = int(input('Welcome to your Shopping list! \n 1) Add Item \n 2) Check Off 
Item \n 3) Print list \n 4) Exit \n Enter a Choice: '))
    if choice == 1:
        add = input('What will you add to the list? ')
        add_item.append(add)
    elif choice == 2:
        remove = int(input('Which item will you check off? '))
        item_2 = add_item.pop(remove)
        
    elif choice == 3:
        for i, item in enumerate(add_item, 1):
            print(i,item.title())
    elif choice == 4:
        print('Goodbye!')
        break
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Printing the popped item with only the first and last letters?

Comment: yes thats my issue I keep trying to slice the len() of the item for everything thats in between the first and last letters but it keeps failing.

Comment: I see you've been on Stack Overflow a while but still haven't taken the [tour], so please start with that. SO is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question, and, based on the comments, you haven't even posted the code you're having difficulty with. So, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask]. You need to show us your best attempt and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: FWIW, those two lists you're showing don't illustrate popping. Popping means removing an item.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to find the new value for your popped list items.

```
def popItemFromList(item):
    # find new value of item popped
    dash_string = ""
    if len(item) > 2:
        for i in range(0, len(item)-2):
            dash_string += "-"
    
    new_value = item[0] + dash_string + item[len(item)-1]
    return new_value

add_item = []
popped_list = []
choice = 0
while(True):
    print(f'current_list: {add_item }')
    print(f'popped_list: {popped_list}')
    choice = int(input('Welcome to your Shopping list! \n 1) Add Item \n 2) Check Off Item \n 3) Print list \n 4) Exit \n Enter a Choice: '))
    if choice == 1:
        add = input('What will you add to the list? ')
        add_item.append(add)
    elif choice == 2:
        remove = int(input('Which item will you check off? '))
        item_2 = add_item.pop(remove)
        popped_list.append(popItemFromList(item_2))

    elif choice == 3:
        for i, item in enumerate(add_item, 1):
            print(i,item.title())
    elif choice == 4:
        print('Goodbye!')
        break
```